# Употребление причастий

Tags: причастия

В предложении «Автор рассказал об изменениях в книге, готовящейся им к переизданию» допущена грамматическая ошибка в употреблении причастного оборота (ЕГЭ 2020). Почему? Ведь можно сказать «книга готовится к изданию автором».

Answer (score 2):

По всей видимости, критика направлена на *расхождение времён* причастия (настоящее время) и глагола (прошедшее) и предполагает для согласования времён вариант "готов**ившей**ся". Однако здесь не видно *ошибки*, поскольку в момент сообщения подготовка книги могла (по име**вшим**ся у говорящего сведениям) продолжаться. Ошибку можно было бы усмотреть, если бы это предложение нашлось в мемуарах, а не, скажем, в ежедневной газете. Этот случай отличается от явно ошибочного "я разговариваю с мамой, готовившей пирог", приводимого здесь: https://obrazovaka.ru/russkiy-yazyk/oshibki-v-prichastiyah В нашем случае имеет место просто ссылка на книгу, которая могла готовиться длительное время, а в примере с пирогом по смыслу разговор происходил одновременно с его приготовлением, поэтому смысл искажается "случившейся" грамматикой: выходит, что некто разговаривает с мамой, которая, как выяснилось, до этого готовила пирог, и имеет какое-то особенное значение или последствия. Поскольку желаемый смысл не в этом, констатируется грамматическая ошибка.

Comment: Они по-другому это объясняют. Им страдательный залог не понравился. https://rus-ege.sdamgia.ru/problem?id=7775 Поджробности - в моем ответе.

Answer (score 1):

В предложении  «Автор рассказал об изменениях в книге, готовящейся им к переизданию» ошибка заключается в неправильном выборе залога. Здесь должен быть страдательный залог,вместо активного.

Правильно: Автор рассказал об изменениях в книге, подготавливаемой им к переизданию.
А в предложении «Книга готовится к изданию автором» все верно. Поскольку здесь использован страдательный залог.

> **Правило:**  При использовании глаголов на -ся следует учитывать возможность совпадения у них двух значений – страдательного и возвратного, что может породить двузначность, например: **Сюда собираются иностранные граждане, заблудившиеся в нашем городе (сами приходят или их собирают?). В подобных случаях необходима соответствующая нужному смыслу правка; ср.: а) Сюда приходят иностранные граждане…; б) Сюда собирают иностранных граждан…**

**Справочник по правописанию и стилистике, Д. Э. Розенталь (см. § 173, п. 4).**

Comment: У причастия "готовящийся" в этом контексте нет "активного" значения. А при использовании "кем" исключается и возвратное.

Comment: Большое спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос взят из весьма сомнительного источника. Существование ошибки - на совести авторов этого пособия.

Смысл их претензий в том, что рукопись готовится не сама, поэтому употребление формы причастия "готовящийся" (возвратной, выступающей обычно в роли страдательного залога) не уместно с готовящейся "кем".

Предлагают заменить на "в книге, **подготавливаемой** им к переизданию".
При этом к самому слову "готовящаяся" претензий нет.
То есть, насколько могу судить, по мнению авторов книга может быть готовящейся, но не "готовящейся им".

Я тут ошибки подобного плана не вижу. Фраза тяжеловесна, согласен, но именно грамматической ошибки тут нет.

Есть примеры из нацкорпуса, это подтверждающие, путь и не самых авторитетных авторов.

> Статья историка искусства Майкла О’Махони ― часть готовящейся им книги
>   о московских подземных «дворцах для народа», где архитектура метро как
>   «синтеза искусств» рассматривается в контексте основных культурных
>   архетипов сталинизма.

Ну или я их совсем не понял.

Comment: _behemoths: Вопрос взят из весьма сомнительного источника. Существование ошибки - на совести авторов этого пособия._ === Авторы источника взяли этот пример у Розенталя. Ошибку чувствовал он. Но это было давно — 60 лет назад...

Comment: @slava1947 вопрос точно не из Розенталя. Он пособий по ЕГЄ не писал. А вот что касается самого предложения, кинте ссілочку, если не затруднит. Гугл фразу эту не нашел.

Comment: @slava1947, Авторы источника взяли этот пример у Розенталя. Ошибку чувствовал он. Но это было давно — 60 лет назад.. А что изменилось сейчас?

Comment: Пример взят из Розенталя, но  у него он рассматривается **не** на предмет _грамматической_ ошибки: https://books.google.ru/books/content?id=d5e8DwAAQBAJ&pg=PA672&img=1&zoom=3&hl=en&ots=wBdsHf4idt&sig=ACfU3U08-L4rgrjOU-tqhrzltg4nPfKECQ&w=1280 В сетевом же источнике - действительно, отсебятина.

Comment: behemoths,прежде чем минусовать, приведите аргументированный ответ, со ссылкой на правило. А ваши "сть примеры из нацкорпуса, это подтверждающие, путь и не самых авторитетных авторов", не является доказательством.

Comment: – Alex_ander, у Розенталя черным по белому написано:. В подобных случаях необходима соответствующая нужному смыслу правка.

Comment: @Alex_ander ну так естественно, у него говорится о ***стилистической*** ошибке, тут вполне можно согласиться. Я написал, что фраза тяжеловесна.

Comment: @Серж во-первых,не коверкайте мой ник, во-вторых, сбавьте обороты. Какое вам еще правило, если я говорю, что ***не вижу нарушений правил***

Comment: _behemothus: А вот что касается самого предложения, кинте ссілочку, если не затруднит. Гугл фразу эту не нашел._ === См. https://books.google.ru/books?id=s0VEAAAAMAAJ&q=%22подготовляемой%22+розенталь&dq=%22подготовляемой%22+розенталь&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj5jfHb84rnAhUPuIsKHUMKAqYQ6AEIWjAI

Comment: https://books.google.ru/books?id=d5e8DwAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q&f=false _При употреблении причастий на -ся со значением страдательного залога нужно учитывать значения, вносимые суффиксом -ся, в частности возможность смешения возвратного и страдательного значений. Например, в место девочка, воспитывающаяся бабушкой; работы, выполняющиеся студентами, **лучше сказать**: девочка, воспитываемая бабушкой; работы, выполняемые студентами._

Comment: @Alex_ander интересно посмотреть на то, кто "смешает" возвратное и страдательное значение в конструкции "воспитывающаяся ***бабушкой***"!

Comment: Там никто не "смешает", просто есть возможность полноценной замены слова, чего я не сказал бы о "приготавливаемой им к изданию". Даже "подготовкой к изданию" издательство занимается, автор только "готовит книгу". Да и бух. отчет может "готовиться бухгалтерией", не  будучи "приготовляемым" :).

Comment: behemothus, если вы не видите явного нарушения, это не говорит еще о том, что нарушений нет. Поэтому, прежде чем минусовать чужие ответы, аргуметируйте научно свой ответ. Иначе это отсебятина.

Comment: Alex_ander, это именно ошибка. Поскольку показателем страдательного залого является сущ. в творительном падеже. А поскольку это стр. залог, то должен быть употреблен стр. залог.

Comment: @Серж я вам ответил на ваше требование сослаться на правило. Все остальное к моему ответу не относится.

Comment: И в нашем примере, и в вашем примере с бабушкой нет разницы. В обоих случаяз есть сущ. в творительном падеже.

Comment: И кстати, пример взят с официального сайта: Решу ЕГЭ.

Comment: @Серж "И в нашем примере, и в вашем примере с бабушкой нет разницы" Это как?

Comment: См: ссылку behemothus.

Comment: Ср:  девочка, воспитывающаяся бабушкой - девочка, воспитываемая бабушкой. Пример с возвратным действительным причастием заменен на страдельное причастие.  В нашем примере тоже возвратное причастие заменено на страдельное причастие.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103432/discussion-between-behemothus-and-).

Comment: Это я о том, что Александр не видит разницы между примером и с бабушкой и примером обсуждаемым.

Comment: Коллеги, уважайте друг друга и продолжите разговор в чате, пожалуйста.

Comment: @Серж Разница в том, что в случае с "бабушкой" есть альтернативная форма причастия от _того же_ глагола (воспитывающаяся -> воспитываемая), в результате чего возможен точный выбор слова (по Розенталю это "лучше" - стилистически). В нашем случае такого выбора нет: "готовимый к изданию" или "приготовляемый к изданию" (от другого глагола!) - стилистически спорные варианты. Грамматической же ошибки нет и по Розенталю.